# type "boost::filesystem::path" could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I've downloaded the trunk repository of [violetland](http://code.google.com/p/violetland/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/system/utility) and I get the error `Type 'boost::filesystem::path' could not be resolved`.
I've installed the boost libraries and `boost/filesystem.hpp` is also included.

How do I solve that problem?

System:
   - linux mint 13 x64
   - eclipse indigo
   - ask for more information if you need them.

Codesample:

```
#ifndef FILEUTILITY_H_
#define FILEUTILITY_H_

#include <vector>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>



class FileUtility {
private:
    boost::filesystem::path m_appPath, m_resPath, m_usrPath;
public:
    enum PathType {
        common = 0, image, anima, sound, music, monsters, weapon, user
    };
    FileUtility(char *argPath);
    static void truncateFullPathToDir(char *path);
    void traceResPath();
    void setFullResPath(std::string path);
    boost::filesystem::path getFullPath(PathType type, std::string resource) const;
    std::vector<std::string> getFilesFromDir(boost::filesystem::path dir);
    unsigned int getFilesCountFromDir(boost::filesystem::path dir);
    std::vector<std::string> getSubDirsFromDir(boost::filesystem::path dir);
    unsigned int getSubDirsCountFromDir(boost::filesystem::path dir);
};

#endif /* FILEUTILITY_H_ */
```

Every usage of `boost::filesystem::path` is marked as error like described above.

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error or a linker error? You say you've included the header, but have you linked against the library?

Comment: the error type is "Semantic Error". What do you mean with "linked against the library"? (Sorry, I only have basic coding skills. I just want to try something bigger than helloworld ;))

Comment: In the line you use to build it, you'll need a `-lboost_filesystem` or whatever library it is for that. If you don't link, the compiler can find the declaration, but the linker can't find the body.

Comment: uhm... where exactly do I need that? In a makefile? Please be more specific. I'm new to programming.

Comment: Somewhere in you project properties should be a spot for adding libraries. I haven't had to do it for Java while using Eclipse, so I'm not sure exactly where. If you use a makefile normally instead, it would go in there.

Comment: I found the place where to put that in (it's the same place where I put "SDL", "SDL_mixer" and so on in) but I'm not sure what to put in there. `locate boost/filesystem` shows me `/usr/include/boost/filesystem` and `/usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp` but eclipse doesn't recognize my input (I tried it with and w/o fileextension and as fullpath)

Comment: You should have a `lib` folder containing `libboost_filesystem.a`. That's the one you need. Just follow the same format as the SDL libraries you have. For example, in one specific C++ IDE, you'd type `boost_filesystem`. It might be different for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install `libboost-filesystem-dev` and `libboost-system-dev`